# Getting Error in installing cmph library in macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I am trying to use the cmph library for the perfect hash function in my code and I am trying to run the simple example http://cmph.sourceforge.net/examples/file_adapter_ex2.c

I installed the library by downloading the cmph package from website and did

1. ./configure
2. make
3. make install

But when I try to run the aforementioned program, I get the following error.

**fatal error: 'cmph.h' file not found**

then I solved that problem by specifying the '/usr/local/include' path through -I flag but I get another issue as follows :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cmph_config_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_config_new", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_config_set_algo", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_io_nlfile_adapter", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_io_nlfile_adapter_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_new", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
  "_cmph_search", referenced from:
      _main in cmph_try1-b75410.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us your linker command ? You may have forgotten to link with the cmph library. including headers isn't enough.

Comment: The file `file_adapter_ex2` should already be built in the `examples` directory after compiling...

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre  : what do you mean by linker  command ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, I had to provide -l option and library name to get it run.